# PHP/SQL - Three Random Images

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to do is display three random images from a database.

I want to use `'SELECT * FROM banner_images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3'`, and at the end of the script, have three vars with the path (DB column) of the random images.

My Database Structure:

```
id    name           path 
1     Banner-101     Banner-101.png 
2     Banner-102     Banner-102.png 
3     Banner-103     Banner-103.png 
4     Banner-104     Banner-104.png 
5     Banner-105     Banner-105.png
```

So for example after the script runs these are the vars

```
$path1 = 'Banner-103.png';
$path2 = 'Banner-105.png';
$path2 = 'Banner-101.png';
```

or something like that.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I tried arrays but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to save query results to the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop the rows and add to an array:

```
$array = array();
$i = 0;

//do your query
//fetch assoc rows
//loop them
while($row){
   $array[$i] = $row['path']; //change banner to field name
$i++;
}
```

If you need those vairable names just assign them after:

```
   $path1 = $array[0];
   $path2 = $array[1];
   $path2 = $array[2];
```

Now you can just echo those 3 variable names like you wanted.

Comment: Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/G3Yxwza9 and I'm getting these errors: http://pastebin.com/Uij6qBEA

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wR0RXxN9 here you go you had to put the fetch assoc in the while brackets

Comment: Also you forgot the `$i ++;` in the while loop as per my answer :)

Comment: Okay. After trying that I'm still getting: **Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\PATH\randBanner.php on line 8**

Comment: Show script again in a new pastebin ill take a look

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZtS105Uw copy paste that, try that i added an error checker on your query. Also check your field is called `banner` its case sensitive.

Comment: Also you have `$rows['banner'];` needs to be `$row['banner'];` (no letter s)

Comment: Ah i just spotted the issue `$array[$i] = $row['path'];`  is what you need

Comment: Got it. :D
I forgot to include information about the database. Works now, thx.